# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'account'

Tags: python-3.x, django, account, django-socialauth, modulenotfounderror

I have added facebook authentication to my django app, but when I click on the `Login with Facebook` button, I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'account'
```

I have an app called `accounts`, and it is in my `INSTALLED_APPS` section of the `settings.py`

Here is my `login.html` template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Log-in{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Log-in</h1>
  {% if form.errors %}
    <p>
      Your username and password didn't match.
      Please try again.
    </p>
  {% else %}
    <p>Please, use the following form to log-in. If you don't have an account <a href="{% url "register" %}">register here</a></p>
  {% endif %}
  <div class="login-form">
    <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
      {{ form.as_p }}
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
      <p><input type="submit" value="Log-in"></p>
    </form>
    <p><a href="{% url "password_reset" %}">Forgotten your password?</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="social">
    <ul>
      <li class="facebook">
        <a href="{% url "social:begin" "facebook" %}">Sign in with Facebook</a>
      </li>
      <li class="twitter">
        <a href="#">Login with Twitter</a>
      </li>
      <li class="google">
        <a href="#">Login with Google</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I am using the default django login view. 
Where is the error?

Comment: i guess it's typo, your app is called `accounts` but you call it some where `account` (mostly in `settings.py` in `INSTALLED_APPS`)

Comment: Yes, thanks for that. I just realized I had put account instead of accounts in my settings.py